# Two Css Files Have Same Class - Remove class from particular Class, How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, class

I am calling two css files in html page having same class name but different properties.

First CSS FILE

```
.text {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

Second CSS FILE

```
.text{
  margin: 0px;
  font: 13px/20px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  padding: 20px 20px 40px 35px;
}
```

I want to remove functionality of .text from Second Css File through Jquery or Javascript ....

Comment: Can you not edit the selectors to make them more specific to the elements that you do want to target? Using JS as a crutch for UI issues isn't a great idea.

Comment: no i can't and also i don't want to change in any css file

Comment: You can delete stylesheet rules but it requires `index` of the rule - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet

Comment: You can't change but you can override the property values font margin and padding

Comment: I agree that using JS for this is not a good idea. If nothing else, it makes the whole website more difficult to maintain, to port etc. Depending on how many elements with class="text" you have, a more elegant solution might be to simply give those elements an inline `style` attribute.

Comment: `no i can't and also i don't want to change in any css file` likely not the best approach. If you are able to change the underlying CSS, as noted by @RoryMcCrossan, you should change it at the source and not implement a change which may later introduce breaking functionality. That said, I appreciate sometimes the shackles of project requirements are sometimes inescapable

Comment: You could add another CSS file/internal `<style>` that negates the rules for `.text`. Bad practice, but if you "can't" edit the current CSS...tack on more? Just make sure it fires/loads after the second CSS rule.

Comment: if you need to do that,you can override the same behavior using script.
$('.text').css({'padding':'0px'}).Something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated in the comments, loading unwanted CSS rules to disable them always and also apply new rules to be the same as another existing rule is a VERY BAD PRACTICE. If you really don't want or can't do it another way, like modifying the existing CSS or adding new CSS rules, you could do this with jQuery:

with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.text').css({'font-family':'verdana', 'font-size':'11px', 'padding':'0', 'margin':'0'});

});
```

Demo: **https://jsfiddle.net/chimos/6g9xmxxo/**

- So here it's giving `padding` and `margin` default values (this can be very problematic if you want `.text` to use other values for margin and padding at some point).
- And `font-family` and `font-size` are defined as in the first CSS rule (this can be very problematic for manteinance, since you have duplicated code and you -or the editor/mantainer- will need to remeber that always to keep things working).